# Working with JOIN - Access SQL

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables that contain names and a few different sets of ID numbers corresponding to those names.
Table1 has columns with: Name, ID1, ID2
Table2 has columns with: Name, ID1, ID3

I want a table that has Name, ID1, ID2, and ID3

I used a left join to get Name, ID1, ID2 from Table1 and get ID3 from Table2, and I used right join to get the remaining ID3 values from Table2, and also the corresponding Name and ID1.  Here's what it looked like:

```
SELECT [Table1].Name, [Table1].ID1, [Table1].ID2, [Table2].ID3
FROM [Table1] LEFT JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].ID1 = [Table2].ID1
UNION 
SELECT [Table2].Name, [Table2].ID1, [Table1].ID2, [Table2].ID3
FROM [Table1] RIGHT JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].ID1 = [Table2].ID1;
```

The problem is that there are some formatting differences in Name between the two tables (for example ID1 = 1 will have Name "University of Nevada" in Table1 and "U. of Nevada" in Table2), so I wind up with duplicate values.  Is there some way to get rid of the duplicates, or change the query so that I don't get them in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: You'll first have to decide which value you prefer in the case of the duplicates, do you want to keep the name from table1 or table2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a line for the second part of you query, it will only select the records from table2 that are not in table1, thus avoiding duplicates: (in this case, when duplicates, the name from table1 will be in your result)

```
SELECT [Table1].Name, [Table1].ID1, [Table1].ID2, [Table2].ID3
FROM [Table1] LEFT JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].ID1 = [Table2].ID1
UNION 
SELECT [Table2].Name, [Table2].ID1, [Table1].ID2, [Table2].ID3
FROM [Table1] RIGHT JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].ID1 = [Table2].ID1
WHERE [Table1].ID1 is null ;
```

I don't know how comfortable you are with queries and understanding them, so just in case it's not clear, I'll quickly explain. The difference is that your second part of your union-query was selecting the entire `Table2` with matching `ID2` from `Table1`. (So the entire green circle in the picture.) So with adding the line `WHERE [Table1].ID1 is null`, we are actually saying to only pick those records of `Table2` where `Table1` has no matching `ID1` value. (So we exclude the overlapping, marked in red, part.)
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks!  I had a vague idea that I only wanted it to look at the null values but I just wasn't sure how to do that.